# How to use Predicate<String>?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflector

I was analyzing some .exe file to covert it into source code, I was not able to understand the lines which had `<>9__0`. What does it mean? Why we use `Predicate<string>`? Could anyone help or it is a junk code generate by .Net Reflector?

```
Console.WriteLine("Processing log file for failed case..." + str4);

while (true)
{
    Predicate<string> <>9__0;
    item = reader.ReadLine();
    if (item != null)
    {
        source.Add(item);
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(source.Count<string>());
    Predicate<string> match = <>9__0;
    if (<>9__0 == null)
    {
        Predicate<string> local1 = <>9__0;
        match = <>9__0 = x => x.ToLower().Contains(match3.ToLower());
    }
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
    foreach (string str8 in source.GetRange(source.FindIndex(match) - 10, 12))
    {
        builder.AppendLine(str8);
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: `<>9__0` this is the result of obfuscation, usually a rename of variable, function, method, delegate, etc...

Comment: If you want to know what the type `Predicate<T>` is (and thus what it could be used for), why don't you look up the documentation for this type?

Comment: What does [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindIndex_System_Predicate__0__) do, and what kind of parameter does it take?

Comment: `List<T>.FindIndex` takes a `Predicate<T>` in parameter, i.e. a delegate able to return a boolean indicating whether an item in the list matches a condition. When  the implementation is provided via an anonymous methods or a lambda, C# gives it a name that you could not give to a method, this is probably why you see `<>9__0`. If you want to validate this, create a C# program passing an anonymous method to `FindIndex` and decompile it with Reflector.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, i deleted my comment already. Right after writing it i realized that vc74 before me explained it much more eloquently than i did in my crude comment ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo no problem.